# Deployment failed with Wildfly 24 and java16

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

With Primefaces 8 on a Wildfly 11 server and Java 9, the project worked beautifully.
I am currently in the process of upgrading to
Primefaces 10, Wildfly 24 and Java 16 and now I get problems. Some are easily solved, while some are so cryptic that I just don't understand them.
Some properties are currently unused - but since I want to keep using them and experimenting with the dependencies, I have of course left them in.

Primefaces 10
Wildfly 24
Java 16

---

here is the log output:

```html
11:55:20,537 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myApp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myApp.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myApp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@16.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/primefaces/context/PrimePartialViewContextFactory (Module "deployment.myApp.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/faces/context/PartialViewContextFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf@24.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.installJsfArtifactComponent(JSFComponentProcessor.java:412)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf@24.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.processJSFArtifactsForInjection(JSFComponentProcessor.java:297)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf@24.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:244)
    at org.jboss.as.server@16.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more

11:55:20,735 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Taedonggang' 12.1.4.Final
11:55:20,773 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'myApp.war#FischingDB'
11:55:20,788 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: FischingDB
    ...]
11:55:20,840 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.20.Final}
11:55:20,842 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:55:20,950 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.5.Final}
11:55:21,319 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myApp.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myApp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myApp.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/primefaces/context/PrimePartialViewContextFactory (Module \"deployment.myApp.war\" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/faces/context/PartialViewContextFactory"}}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a PrimeFaces dependency. What does your POM look like?

Comment: I am trying to implement the primefaces 6.2 in my legacy project . with JSF-1.2, wildfly 26 and java 8